# Zend Studio 7.1 PHPUnit Test Case wizard does not populate "Element to Test"

Tags: php, phpunit, zend-studio

When I follow the instructions in ZS documentation to create a phpunit test case, the wizard returns no objects to select on the ["Element to Test"](http://files.me.com/mjstelly/ygebui) line. Selecting "browse" provides an empty dialog box. The PHPUnit path in my preferences shows "/Applications/zend/zs710/plugins/com.zend.php.phpunit_7.1.0.v20091120-0900/resources/library/". What else can I check to see why I cannot create a test case? I'm new to ZS and PHP, so I have no idea how to troubleshoot this.
 Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem was my unfamiliarity with the tool. I was trying to create the PHPUnit test on PHP file. Quite by accident, I tried performing the same action on the class within the file in the PHP Explorer and it worked. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

You should start type an existing class you want to exercise in your test case, it's like an "open type" dialog...

Comment: Thanks for submitting your response. Sorry, but your suggestion did not work in this case. When I type the name of either the class or function, the dialog box displays "There is no element 'indexAction' in project 'esdev'". Something is clearly incorrect because I started the dialog by clicking on indexController where indexAction resides.